# Инициализация класса массивом

Tags: c++, c++11

у меня есть следующий класс со следующим конструктором:

```
template<class Type>
class Matrix4x4 
{ 
public:
    ...
    Matrix4x4(const Type* array) noexcept;
    ...
private:
    Type mElements[MATRIX_SIZE] = { 
        1, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 1, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 1, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 1
    };
}

template<class Type>
Matrix4x4<Type>::Matrix4x4(const Type* array) noexcept
{
    for (std::uint8_t i = 0; i < MATRIX_SIZE; i += ROW_SIZE)
    {
        mElements[i] = array[i];
        mElements[i + 1] = array[i + 1];
        mElements[i + 2] = array[i + 2];
        mElements[i + 3] = array[i + 3];
    }
}
```

И когда я хочу сделать вот так:

```
Math::Matrix4x4f matrix({
    mx.getX(), mx.getY(), mx.getZ(), -dot(mx, eye),
    my.getX(), my.getY(), my.getZ(), -dot(my, eye),
    mz.getX(), mz.getY(), mz.getZ(), -dot(mz, eye),
    0.0,       0.0,       0.0,       1.0
});
```

Я получаю следующую ошибку(VS2017):

```
Error   C2664   'Math::Matrix4x4<float>::Matrix4x4(Math::Matrix4x4<float> &&) noexcept': cannot convert argument 1 from 'initializer list' to 'const Type *'
```

Как видно из ошибки он ожидает, что конструктор принимает initializer_list. Вопрос заключается в следующем, можно ли как-то привести тип к массиву, либо указателю, чтобы не передавать initializer_list с этим новым синтаксисом инициализации?

Comment: А почему бы не использовать как раз новый синтаксис инициализации? Имеет смысл избегать использования массивов и указателей.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<strike>Не меняя кода - нет, нельзя.</strike>

Создать временный массив при помощи `{}`-инициализатора можно, если завернуть его тип в "однословное" имя

```
using FA = float[MATRIX_SIZE];

...
FA{
  mx.getX(), mx.getY(), mx.getZ(), -dot(mx, eye),
  my.getX(), my.getY(), my.getZ(), -dot(my, eye),
  mz.getX(), mz.getY(), mz.getZ(), -dot(mz, eye),
  0.0,       0.0,       0.0,       1.0
}
```

однако взять адрес временного массива (или его элемента) для передачи в ваш конструктор вам никто не позволит.

А вот если вы переведете свой конструктор на использование ссылки

```
Matrix4x4(const Type (&array)[MATRIX_SIZE]) noexcept;
```

то все становится возможным

```
using FA = float[MATRIX_SIZE];
Math::Matrix4x4f matrix(FA{
  mx.getX(), mx.getY(), mx.getZ(), -dot(mx, eye),
  my.getX(), my.getY(), my.getZ(), -dot(my, eye),
  mz.getX(), mz.getY(), mz.getZ(), -dot(mz, eye),
  0.0,       0.0,       0.0,       1.0
});
```

---

Хотя я поспешил со своим "не меняя кода - нет, нельзя". Вы можете сохранить конструктор в его нынешнем виде и использовать `std::array` в качестве промежуточного типа

```
Math::Matrix4x4f matrix(
  std::array<float, MATRIX_SIZE>{
    mx.getX(), mx.getY(), mx.getZ(), -dot(mx, eye),
    my.getX(), my.getY(), my.getZ(), -dot(my, eye),
    mz.getX(), mz.getY(), mz.getZ(), -dot(mz, eye),
    0.0,       0.0,       0.0,       1.0
  }.data()
);
```